# Leaflet check if marker is within 5 meters of other marker check

Tags: javascript, leaflet, latitude-longitude

How would I check if some markers are within 5 meters range to?

```js
L.marker([56.41083875205333, 8.864636421203615], {icon: HydrantIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hydrant  1");
L.marker([56.41069629842804, 8.868584632873537], {icon: HydrantIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hydrant  2");
L.marker([56.40941419180167, 8.866181373596193], {icon: HydrantIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hydrant  3");
```

This is the code I use to put down the markers these would need to check if there are within 5 meters of the "Hydrant" markers above and it would probably also need a foreach since its need to check for all the "Hydrant" markers

```js
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);

function requestGeoJson(){
    fetch('https://laerkeholt.dk/admin/get-features')
      .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
      .then(function(json){
         geoJsonLayer.clearLayers().addData(json).bindPopup('ID: ' + json.properties.id);
         setTimeout(requestGeoJson, 5000);
      });
};
requestGeoJson();
```

Comment: You do have the coordinates of the markers, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply leverage Leaflet's [`distanceTo`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#latlng-distanceto) method:

```js
var latLng1 = [56.41083875205333, 8.864636421203615];
var latLng2 = [56.41069629842804, 8.868584632873537];

L.latLng(latLng1).distanceTo(latLng2);
```

Comment: Yes, but how would i check if any of the markers from the geojson are in a 5 meters distance to any of the Hydrant Markers